# Prevent input text scale

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode7

I bought the book [Beginning iPhone Development with Swift 2: Exploring the iOS SDK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484217535) and followed the tutorials, how to build IOS app.

I created two input fields that looks as follow:
[image]
and when I run on the simulator on IPhone 6S, then the second input field get scaled.
[image]
The attribute inspector from looks like:
[image]
And at last the size inspector:
[image]

How can avoid that?

**Update**
The constraints looks as follow:
[image]

Comment: show us more details about constraints on Number text field

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `centerY` for vertical constraint. This is the one that collides with your height. Just use `top` like for UITextViews and it should work fine.

Simply change `centerY` in `Number:` to `top` and that will work.

Comment: The first input field, I did not set height constraint too.

Comment: Sorry, I just found out that something else was the issue. I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Sorry, where I have to change? I can not find it. Sorry I am very  a beginner. I updated my post above.